# Fast convert JSON column into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm reading data from a database (50k+ rows) where one column is stored as JSON. I want to extract that into a pandas dataframe. 
The snippet below works fine but is fairly inefficient and really takes forever when run against the whole db.
Note that not all the items have the same attributes and that the JSON have some nested attributes.

How could I make this faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/7L86m9R2', \
                 header=None, index_col=0, names=['data'])

df.data.apply(json.loads) \
       .apply(pd.io.json.json_normalize)\
       .pipe(lambda x: pd.concat(x.values))
###this returns a dataframe where each JSON key is a column
```

Comment: Would `df.data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))` do?

Comment: Can you store your pasted data in a different (any kind of a standard) format?

Comment: @JohnGalt: works but that doesn't flatten the dict

Comment: @MaxU: if possible, I'd prefer not to change the scraping script

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[json_normalize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) takes an already processed json string or a pandas series of such strings.

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.data.apply(json.loads))
```

---

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/7L86m9R2', \
                 header=None, index_col=0, names=['data'])
```

Comment: Thanks. That's faster than your first solution ;)

Comment: I get this error : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: @AliMirzaei Replace it with your own column name.

Comment: It would be great if your answer and Madhur Yadav's combined so that it included a example.

Answer (score 19):

I think you can first convert `string` column `data` to `dict`, then create `list` of `numpy arrays` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and last [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://pastebin.com/raw/7L86m9R2', \
                 header=None, index_col=0, names=['data'])

a = df.data.apply(json.loads).values.tolist() 
print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(a))
```

Another idea:

```
 df = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
```

Comment: Thanks- That's about 100x faster than my initial approach. The only issue is that this doesn't expand the nested dicts. Would that be possible ?

Comment: Check another answer ;)

Comment: Quick question @jezrael
the order of the csv and the df you are making from variable 'a' is the same right ?
first record will be first record and second will be second and so on..
will they ever shuffle ?

Comment: @skybunk - Yes, exactly. There is no reason for `shuffle`

Answer (score 2):

> data = {      "events":[
>         {
>            "timemillis":1563467463580,
>            "date":"18.7.2019",
>            "time":"18:31:03,580",
>            "name":"Player is loading",
>            "data":""
>         },
>         {
>            "timemillis":1563467463668,
>            "date":"18.7.2019",
>            "time":"18:31:03,668",
>            "name":"Player is loaded",
>            "data":"5"
>         } ] }

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
result = json_normalize(data,'events')
print(result)
```