# Regexp from text to pandas columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

I have CSV file with column names and values in json like format. I would like to extract that column names and values to pandas.

I tried to use regexp but I cant find good code to extract what I want.

One cell on my data:

```
[{u'name': u'svSum7Days', u'value': 0.0}, {u'name': u'svSum91Days', u'value': 44.0}, {u'name': u'svSum364Days', u'value': 121.0}, {u'name': u'newPositionsCount60Days', u'value': 0}, {u'name': u'currentBalance', u'value': 2915.0}]
```

After the 'name': is column name and after that is value. I have hundreds of cells where all the columns are the same.

I would like to extract to Pandas dataframe those column names and input values from all cells to them. Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: Use a `json` parser!

Comment: Can you test [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209764/fast-convert-json-column-into-pandas-dataframe) ?

Comment: It is not exactly a json string, so json parsers do not work

Answer (score 1):

```
use json
db = json.load(open('/path/to/json/file'))
len(db)
```

Check

**Out** db size as an integer

```
db[0].keys()
```

Check
**Out** dict_keys[.....]