# unpack dictionary values in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have this dataframe from where I need to exact the act1omschr from the column adresactiviteit, however sinds it is an object with a list and dict I don't know how to extract these values.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `json.loads` should work ... but you are gonna lose alot of the power of the dataframe ... it might be slowish

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that's not a dictionary, but a 'json' (java script object notation). It's a bit like a csv but with nested values and pretty comumn especially for web data.

Pandas has a function called 'json_normalize' which should help. For specifically using it on one column, [this was answered pretty well over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209764/fast-convert-json-column-into-pandas-dataframe). You should more or less be able to use the exact code given.